# How to make a dissolving transition with LaTeX Beamer?

Tags: beamer, pdf, presentations

For a presentation I want to visualise the growth of a tree using a dissolving transition. Under Linux it works fine to use `\transdissolve` for that, Evince properly draws the transition.

Unfortunately, I am forced to give the talk using Windows with Adobe Reader 10. In that program, the transition is displayed not by dissolving, but by a strange square effect, where many small squares are drawn.

How can I get Adobe Reader to make the proper transition?

Comment: I'm not sure this is going to be easy. Something with a `animate` involving TikZ overlays of varying opacities?

Comment: The way `\transdissolve` works is it puts a special command in the PDF that the *reader* interprets.  What you're seeing is Acrobat Reader's interpretation of "dissolve."  So I'm not sure it's possible to trick it into something else.

Comment: Is the reader maybe mixing up the command with another one? Meaning that another transition command might do just what I want?

Comment: No real answer to your question: You could use [`Impressive`](http://impressive.sourceforge.net/) instead of Adobe Reader for your presentation - it's a highly customizable presentation program for Windows/Linux/Mac with a variety of page transitions and other useful features.

Comment: I second using impressive. Although it's not always an option if you're not using your own computer...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using [**`\transfade`**](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf#subsection.14.3) instead of `\transdissolve`. It <s>doesn't seem to be documented in the [beamer manual](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) ([yet](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/165)), but it works nevertheless and</s> produces a nice, soft transition in Adobe Reader X.